# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'quest' of undefined

Tags: javascript, dom, frontend, javascript-objects, web-deployment

I know that this question may have been asked before but I believe that this awesome community can forgive me for this :) 
I am developing (Quiz time) app but there's a bug that's is killing me :(
When I run this application every and press the lock button it acts as wanted but after a random number of clicks (may be 4 or 2) It stops and gives me this error :

```
         Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'quest' of undefined
at QuestionReset
```

Here's the code

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
var overwallScore = 0;
//prototype
function Question(quest, option1, option2, option3, correct) {
    this.quest = quest;
    this.option1 = option1;
    this.option2 = option2;
    this.option3 = option3;
    this.correct = correct;

}
//creating questions
var question1 = new Question("1 + 1", 2, 3, 3, 1);
var question2 = new Question("2 + 2", 4, 3, 3, 2);
var question3 = new Question("3 + 3", 6, 3, 3, 3);
var question4 = new Question("4 + 4", 8, 3, 3, 1);
var question5 = new Question("5 + 5", 10, 3, 3, 2);
var question6 = new Question("6 + 6", 12, 3, 3, 3);
//the questions array
var questions = [];
//pushing questions to array
questions.push(question1);
questions.push(question2);
questions.push(question3);
questions.push(question4);
questions.push(question5);
questions.push(question6);
var randomQuestionIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);

function QuestionPre() {
    randomQuestionIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
    document.querySelector("#question").innerHTML = questions[randomQuestionIndex].quest;
    document.querySelector(".option-1").innerHTML = questions[randomQuestionIndex].option1;
    document.querySelector(".option-2").innerHTML = questions[randomQuestionIndex].option2;
    document.querySelector(".option-3").innerHTML = questions[randomQuestionIndex].option3;

}
QuestionPre();

function QuestionReset() {
    randomQuestionIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
    document.querySelector("#question").innerHTML = questions[randomQuestionIndex].quest;
    document.querySelector(".option-1").innerHTML = questions[randomQuestionIndex].option1;
    document.querySelector(".option-2").innerHTML = questions[randomQuestionIndex].option2;
    document.querySelector(".option-3").innerHTML = questions[randomQuestionIndex].option3;
}
document.querySelector(".lock-btn").addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (document.querySelector(".option-" + questions[randomQuestionIndex].correct + "-check").checked === true) {
        alert("Correct, such a Genius !");
        overwallScore = overwallScore + 1;
        QuestionReset();
    } else {
        alert("Wrong mate, such a bad luck !");
        randomQuestionIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
        QuestionReset();


    }
}); });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `var randomQuestionIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);`

the value of `randomQuestionIndex` might go beyond the range
remove the `+1` part and it should work fine.

Comment: THIS JUST WORKED MATE AND I DON'T KNOW WHY THANKS GOD FOR SENDING HIM TO ME , THANKS  MATE THIS JUST MY DAY MUCH BETTER ! I WAS DOING THIS FOR MY GOD DAMNED FRENCH CRUSH THANKS YOU AGAIN PLZ WRITE IT AS ANSWER SO I CAN MARK IT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the line

> var randomQuestionIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);

The value of `randomQuestionIndex` might go out of range. Just remove the `+1` part and it should work.