# Ajax timer reset on click

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have form of dynamic data, each one of my data has timer (countdown) when i click and go to next pages timer will get conflict with old data (new timer and old timer will overlapping each other)

## Screen record

[image: one]

> As you see my first data has timer of `35 seconds` and second one
>   timer of `2 minutes` they are overlapping in second page.

## Code

```
var index = 0;
$("#clicks").click(function(){
    // timer function
    function timer(seconds, countdownTimer, callback) {
        var days = Math.floor(seconds / 24 / 60 / 60);
        var hoursLeft = Math.floor((seconds) - (days * 86400));
        var hours = Math.floor(hoursLeft / 3600);
        var minutesLeft = Math.floor((hoursLeft) - (hours * 3600));
        var minutes = Math.floor(minutesLeft / 60);
        var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
        if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
            remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;
        }
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
        if (seconds == 0) {
            clearInterval(countdownTimer);
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Times Up!";
            $("#clicks").attr("disabled", true);
            $("#clicks").hide();
            $('.answerPanel').html('<div class="text-center text-danger">OH NO! <br> Times Up!</div>');
        } else {
            seconds--;
        }
        //Pass seconds param back to the caller.
        callback(seconds);
    }
    //We pass the countdownTimer param into the timer function as well.
    var countdownTimer = null,
    seconds = data.quizzes[index].quiz_time;
    countdownTimer = setInterval(function() {
        timer(seconds, countdownTimer, function(_seconds){
            seconds = _seconds;
        })
    }, 1000);

    // printing function
    if(typeof  data.quizzes[index] != 'undefined'){
        var html = '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"><div class="pull-left questionTitle">'+data.quizzes[index].question+'</div><div class="pull-right" id="countdown"></div></div></div>';
        if(data.quizzes[index].choices.length > 0){
            html+='<div class="col-md-12">';
            if(data.quizzes[index].question_type == 'multiple'){
                data.quizzes[index].choices.forEach((element, index, array) => {
                    html+='<div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">';
                    html+='<input id="choice" name="choice" type="checkbox" value="'+element.choice+'" required>';
                    html+='<label for="checkbox2">'+element.choice+'</label>';
                    html+='</div>';
                });
            } else {
                data.quizzes[index].choices.forEach((element, index, array) => {
                    html+='<div class="radio radio-primary">';
                    html+='<input id="choice" name="choice" type="radio" value="'+element.choice+'" required>';
                    html+='<label>'+element.choice+'</label>';
                    html+='</div>';
                });
            }
            html+='</div>';
        }
        $(".answerPanel").html(html);
        index++;
    }

    if(data.quizzes.length > index+1) {
        $("#clicks").html("Next");
    }
    if(data.quizzes.length === index) {
        $("#clicks").html("Send");
        $('#clicks').removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-success saveAnswers');
    }
    //end of printing function
});
```

**Any idea?**

## Update

For better investigation here is my full script

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        var table = $("#projectTable").DataTable({
            'createdRow': function(row, data, dataIndex) {
                if (dataIndex == 0) {
                    $(row).addClass('selected');
                };
                setTimeout( function () {
                    table.draw();
                }, 100 );
            }
        });
        $('#projectTable tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.projectName').empty();

            table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            $('.projectName').empty();
            var projectId = $(this).data('id');

            //quizzes
            $.ajax({
                type:'GET',
                url:'{{url('dashboard/getQuizzeswithChoices')}}/'+projectId,
                beforeSend: function(data) {
                    console.log("click - ajax before send", data);
                },
                success:function(data){
                    $('.answerPanel').html('');
                    $('#clicks').html("Next");
                    $('#clicks').removeClass('btn-success saveAnswers').addClass('btn-primary');
                    $('.projectName').append('of ', data.project.name);
                    console.log(data);
                    //return existed data to quizzes
                    var index = 0;
                    var countdownTimer = null;
                    $("#clicks").click(function(){
                        // timer function
                        function timer(seconds, countdownTimer, callback) {
                            var days = Math.floor(seconds / 24 / 60 / 60);
                            var hoursLeft = Math.floor((seconds) - (days * 86400));
                            var hours = Math.floor(hoursLeft / 3600);
                            var minutesLeft = Math.floor((hoursLeft) - (hours * 3600));
                            var minutes = Math.floor(minutesLeft / 60);
                            var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
                            if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
                                remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;
                            }
                            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
                            if (seconds == 0) {
                                clearInterval(countdownTimer);
                                document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Times Up!";
                                $("#clicks").attr("disabled", true);
                                $("#clicks").hide();
                                $('.answerPanel').html('<div class="text-center text-danger">OH NO! <br> Times Up!</div>');
                            } else {
                                seconds--;
                            }
                            //Pass seconds param back to the caller.
                            callback(seconds);
                        }
                        //We pass the countdownTimer param into the timer function as well.
                        if (countdownTimer != null) {
                            clearInterval(countdownTimer);
                        }
                        seconds = data.quizzes[index].quiz_time;
                        countdownTimer = setInterval(function() {
                            timer(seconds, countdownTimer, function(_seconds){
                                seconds = _seconds;
                            })
                        }, 1000);

                        // printing function
                        if(typeof data.quizzes[index] != 'undefined'){
                            var html = '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"><div class="pull-left questionTitle">'+data.quizzes[index].question+'</div><div class="pull-right" id="countdown"></div></div></div>';
                            if(data.quizzes[index].choices.length > 0){
                                html+='<div class="col-md-12">';
                                if(data.quizzes[index].question_type == 'multiple'){
                                    data.quizzes[index].choices.forEach((element, index, array) => {
                                        html+='<div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">';
                                        html+='<input id="choice" name="choice" type="checkbox" value="'+element.choice+'">';
                                        html+='<label for="checkbox2">'+element.choice+'</label>';
                                        html+='</div>';
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    data.quizzes[index].choices.forEach((element, index, array) => {
                                        html+='<div class="radio radio-primary">';
                                        html+='<input id="choice" name="choice" type="radio" value="'+element.choice+'">';
                                        html+='<label>'+element.choice+'</label>';
                                        html+='</div>';
                                    });
                                }
                                html+='</div>';
                            }
                            $(".answerPanel").html(html);
                            index++;
                        }

                        if(data.quizzes.length > index+1) {
                            $("#clicks").html("Next");
                        }
                        if(data.quizzes.length === index) {
                            $("#clicks").html("Send");
                            $('#clicks').removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-success saveAnswers');
                        }
                        //end of printing function

                        //send form data
                        $('#sendAnswers').submit(function(e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            let formData = $(this).serialize();
                            console.log(formData);
                            // $.post({
                            //     type: 'POST',
                            //     url: '{{route('quizzes.store')}}',
                            //     data: formData
                            // });
                        });

                        $('.saveAnswers').click(function() {
                            $('#sendAnswers').submit();
                        });
                        //send form data
                    });
                }
            });

        });
        $("#projectTable tbody tr:first-child").trigger("click");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I must have missed it. What is the question?

Comment: Why are you defining the timer function inside the function that creates the quiz? Shouldn't you make them separately?

Comment: @gforce301 resetting the timer when i go to next pages

Comment: When the user changes pages, you need to clear the old timer and start a new one.

Comment: @SwimmerF all sort of suggestions are welcome, please feel free to place an answer

Comment: The timer variable probably needs to be a global variable, not local to the click handler, so it can be cleared on a different click.

Comment: @Barmar if i move my timer function above `$("#clicks").click(function(){` it only gets first page timer for all pages, but probably i did it wrong, please feel free to share your idea code with me

Comment: You should put `var countdownTimer = null` as global variable, and on every click, first check `if (countdownTimer != null) { clearInterval(countdownTimer); }`. that should do the job

Comment: @CHANist that seems to work however when i reach latest page and i click on button it returns `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'quiz_time' of undefined` how would i prevent this?

Comment: Where do you set `index`?

Comment: @Barmar here`var index = 0; var countdownTimer = null; $("#clicks").click(function(){`

Comment: @mafortis just a small remark, incase `var index = 0; ` is set as global variable. As I think name clash can be quite common if such variable is set globally, just wrap this part of code with IIFE. i.e. (function() { // your code})(). If you already do it, just forget what I say.

Comment: There must be something wrong with the code that's supposed to stop when `index` gets too high.

Comment: @CHANist yes my script starts with `$(function() {`

Comment: @Barmar would you like to see FULL script?

Comment: @Barmar updated

Comment: @CHANist mybe my new update can help you find something that i didn't?

Comment: @Barmar can be something about this part?  Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46530109/8490993

Comment: @mafortis the code makes me feel a bit weird, but I am hoping `#clicks` element is not lie in `#projectTable tbody tr` elemenet, as the event will propagate outwards. Not sure if it is the scenerio anyway, but maybe event bubbling may be the reason.

Comment: @CHANist I wrapped up my code with if condition and it doesn't return error anymore `if(typeof data.quizzes[index] !== 'undefined'){seconds = data.quizzes[index].quiz_time;}` thank you

Comment: can you print out the log for easier debugging, I think you may solve the issue in minutes. `console.log(\`quizzes, ${JSON.stringify(data.quizzes)}, index: ${index}\`)`;

Comment: @CHANist here you go https://codeshare.io/G7jVzk this is when i click next button for first time